# Add path to node in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I use Plesk and CentOS. My npm and node bin are in a specific folder :

```
/opt/plesk/node/9/bin
```

When I try to run `/opt/plesk/node/9/bin/npm install`, I have this error :

> node-sass@4.10.0 install /var/www/app/node_modules/node-sass
>
> node scripts/install.js
>
> sh: node: command not found

I guess it's because Plesk doesn't set PATH for node, I have multiple versions of Node.

Can I set the path to node in the *package.json* of my project ? or set this path in an other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Node binary was not found by npm due to no node binary in the current PATH.

Try add the variable into a global npm config file. Using shell command:

```
echo "scripts-prepend-node-path=true" >> /opt/plesk/node/9/etc/.npmrc
```

Or you can use File Manager of PleskUI to add `scripts-prepend-node-path=true` into `.npmrc` file. Create the file if it does not exist.